# CICS Bundle and JSON webservice

Tags: json, cics

I am doing a POC for a client account ,where I am  trying to setup and Request -response model of JSON web-service where CICS acts as client. I have created 2 bundles separately for placing  request  jsbinds and response jsbind files. now the problem is  that only one of my bundle is active  (either request or response)  and every time i have to discard one bundle and need to install the other one . is there a way i can install multiple bundles simultaneously in a CICS region ? or can the bundle be discarded and another bundle be installed by the application program  dynamically it self

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely install multiple CICS bundles simultaneously in a CICS region.

The first thing to check is the CICS regions job log for messages explaining why the second bundle failed to install (or failed to enable). The messages will likely start with DFHRL.

If you have installed each of the bundles successfully (albeit independently), then it could be something as simple as a naming clash. Make sure each bundle has a unique name.

This Redbooks publication (especially chapter 11) should be useful:
[Implementing IBM CICS JSON Web Services for Mobile Applications](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248161.html?Open)

Comment: yes it fails because the second bundle also has same bundle id name . Now how  to generate the bundle id with different name ? every time I generate a bundle it creates bundle with same bundle id "bundle" below is the input iam passing to DFHJS2LS for generating bindfils     but nowhere I am mentioning about bundle id  not sure where the bundle id is picked up from (note I dont have cics explorer all I am using the RDO to define everything.)

Comment: 4    LANG=COBOL                                                         
5    BUNDLE= /u/cic03/bundle                                            
6    LOGFILE=/u/cic03/jsonlog                                           
7    MAPPING-LEVEL=4.1                                                  
8    PDSLIB=//CIC03.JSON.TRNSFORM.OUT                                   
9    PDSMEM=CPYBK2                                                      
0    JSONTRANSFRM=CRDTRQSI                                              
1  CHEMA=/cicsts/cicsts53/test/schemas/xmltransform/CRDTRQSI.jsJSON-

Comment: Have you managed to sort this problem out? The follow-up from Remko was good advice.

Thank you for supplying the JS2LS parameters.
You should not be using the same parameters for both bundles. (Otherwise the bundles will be outputted to the same location - BUNDLE is an output parameter)

Take a look at chapter 11 in the Redbook that I previously linked to. There is a step by step guide for your usecase.

Comment: Yes My problem was sorted out by following RemKo provided  idea . thanks to Remko and everyone supported .

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the bundle-id is unique. The bundle-id is generated from the bundle directory name, and can be found inside the META-INF/cics.xml file.

The CICS region job log will mention "The CICS resource lifecycle manager has failed to create the BUNDLE resource ", but does not give a reason as to why creation has failed.

There is, however, a line stating "BUNDLE resource  is being created with BUNDLEID  and version .". You could check to see if the bundle-ids are the same for both bundles.

Comment: yes it fails because the second bundle also has same bundle id name . Now how to generate the bundle id with different name ? every time I generate a bundle it creates bundle with same bundle id "bundle" below is the input iam passing to DFHJS2LS for generating bindfils but nowhere I am mentioning about bundle id not sure where the bundle id is picked up from (note I dont have cics explorer all I am using the RDO to define everything.)

Comment: 4 LANG=COBOL 5 BUNDLE= /u/cic03/bundle 6 LOGFILE=/u/cic03/jsonlog 7 MAPPING-LEVEL=4.1 8 PDSLIB=//CIC03.JSON.TRNSFORM.OUT 9 PDSMEM=CPYBK2 0 JSONTRANSFRM=CRDTRQSI 1 CHEMA=/cicsts/cicsts53/test/schemas/xmltransform/CRDTRQSI.jsJSON-

Comment: The bundle-id is automatically generated using te last part of the specified bundle directory, in your case this would be 'bundle' (from '/u/cic03/bundle'). Use different bundle directories for both bundles, and the bundle-id will be different as well. You could also edit your generated cics.xml to change the bundle-id yourself, but I would advise against that...